# Passing Object as function parameter but getting undefined in function body in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, parameters, redux-toolkit

I've written resetpasswordHandler form with react-form-hook package and passing the data object to authSlice along with resetToken (string) as parameter.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { reset, resetPassword } from "../features/auth/authSlice";

const ResetPassword = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      password: "",
      confirm_password: ""
    },
    mode: "onTouched",
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const {resetToken} = useParams()
  const {isSuccess} = useSelector(state => state.auth)
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const resetPwdHandler = async (data) => {
    console.log(data) //{password: '123', confirm_password: '123'}
    await dispatch(resetPassword({data, resetToken}))
    await dispatch(reset())
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if(isSuccess){
      navigate('/login', {replace: true})
    }
  }, [isSuccess, dispatch, navigate])
  

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(resetPwdHandler)}>
        <label className="input-lable">Enter Password</label>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          {...register("password", {
            required: "Password is required",
          })}
        />
        <p>{errors.password?.message}</p>

        <label className="input-lable">Confirm Password</label>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          {...register("confirm_password", {
            required: true,
            validate: (val) => {
                if (watch('password') !== val) {
                    console.log("hi")
                    return 'Confirm Password must be same as password'
                }
            }
          })}
        />
        <p>{errors.confirm_password?.message}</p>

        <button>Reset Password</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResetPassword;
```

**Here is reset password code in authSlice**

```
export const resetPassword = createAsyncThunk("auth/resetPassword", async ({passwordData, resetToken}, {rejectWithValue}) => {
    console.log(passwordData, resetToken) //getting undefined for passwordData
    try {
        return await resetUserPassword(passwordData, resetToken)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        const message = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.errMsg)
        // navigate('/login')
        return rejectWithValue(message)
    }
})
```

How to get the data back the passowrd data inside createAyncThunk?

I've tried to destructure password data object but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is a mistake in the way you are passing the data to the resetPassword action, here:

```
await dispatch(resetPassword({data, resetToken}))
```

In this line, you are creating an object with properties data and resetToken instead of passing the data and resetToken as separate arguments to the resetPassword action.

Try changing it to this:

```
await dispatch(resetPassword(data, resetToken))
```

i'm not completely sure, but hope it helps! :)

Comment: In that case, resetToken becomes undefined